# Software running on server and using on clients

Tags: networking, cloud

I have one powerfull server computer and 5-10 local machines (weak PCs). All users have to use expensive software (MatLab for example)

Can I make such a 'cloud' network? Software is installed on server (Windows + software) but local machines are on Linux and are using software from server? All clients may use one software program at one time.

Is it legally? (in the meanning of licenses of software)

How this can be realised?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that yes, using something like MS Terminal Services or Citrix and then get a RDP/VNC client on the Linux clients - whether it was covered by your application's terms of service is entirely dependant on the specifics of your licence - only you can find this out by speaking with the vendor/s.

Answer (score 1):

If you went this route it would end up being more of an RDS set up.  You could alternatively see if you could use ThinApp to virtualize the Matlab app, although I'm not sure it can be virtualized.